# Audio recording javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possibly in Jquery or Javascript, without the use of libraries to record audio for X seconds and save to a audio file. I've looked at getUserMedia, an I see that it can retrieve audio and video from the webcam. I am currently using the webcam with another library: [Clmtracker](https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr) and for that reason I would want to try and do this without any more external libraries.

I want to store the recorded audio in a div. I am currently taking a picture and assigning it a unique name, so I am wondering how I can capture a short section of audio and store it in the same generated div.

Question: How can I achieve getting audio for 5 seconds from webcam?
Sub-Question: How can I store that in an  element within a div?

My Code for capturing Img and Data on my page

```
   function capturePage() {
      var now = new Date();

      if (nextAllowedCapture <= now) {
          // Do capture logic
          audioElement.play();

          counting++
          console.log("Capturing...");
          $(".capturing").show().delay(500).fadeOut(3000);
          var innerDiv = document.createElement('div'),
              innerDivImg = document.createElement('canvas'),
              image = document.createElement('img'),
              ul = document.createElement('ul');

          innerDiv.className = 'divCreate';

          innerDiv.id = 'img' + counting;

          innerDivImg.height = 450;
          innerDivImg.width = 600;
          innerDivImg.getContext('2d').drawImage(vid, 0, 0);

          image.id = 'image' + counting;
          image.src = innerDivImg.toDataURL();
          image.className = 'divCreateImg';

          innerDiv.appendChild(image);
          innerDiv.appendChild(ul);

          document.getElementById('galleryWrapper').appendChild(innerDiv);


          $('#measurements h4').each(function () {
              $("#" + innerDiv.id + " " + 'ul').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + ': ' + $(this).next().text());
          });
          nextAllowedCapture = new Date();
          nextAllowedCapture.setSeconds(nextAllowedCapture.getSeconds() + coolDownSeconds);
      } else {

          nextCapTime = (nextAllowedCapture.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000;
          console.log("Can't capture again yet. This function can be executed again in " +
              (nextAllowedCapture.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000 +
              " seconds.");



      }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can see the code for Recorder.js as an example which implements the capture audio functionality and saves it in wav format using getUserMedia annd yes, just html5 and javascript.

**Now you might say that you asked without any plugins. In fact, I checked the code for recorder.js which is just 90 lines of plain javascript, just html5 and javascript.**

**UPDATE:** I found one [online demo](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html) which experiments with this and it seems to work fine and all source code is open. You might want to check that out.
Here is the link:
[Recorder JS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/recorder.js)

Here is another link to tweak it and make it more functional.
[Recording MP3 Using Only HTML5 and JavaScript](http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/)

Comment: i played with those the other day and they aren't ready for prime time yet. specifically, you have to mute the device audio to record or else suffer horrible feedback, and the resulting mp3 from that blog post is twice as long as the input wav. it's also a chrome/FF only thing for now. i hope something better comes along. the two links are promising and neat, but not quite usable at this time.

Comment: Yes, I realized that too when I started reading about it. Seems to have some buffer issues but hey, it is possible. Only thing that is remaining is to make it more efficient. Need to do more reading myself though.

Comment: this is one of those HTML5 "are we there yet?"s that's taken so long i want to turn around and go home.

Comment: Can you tell me is this example working for you, actually looks fairly promising but it doesnt seem to work for me in Chrome http://audior.ec/recordmp3js/

Comment: @DanW: works with the limits i described earlier (double length and feedback if the device volume is any louder than a whisper). that said, the mp3s are MUCH smaller than the wave output, so even double (evidently without fancy zero-bit silence) is still a lot better to store client-side. if you can live with that and a muted audio on the recording device, this does what advertised.

Comment: I am getting absolutely no sound coming back out after recording. In Chrome and FF

Comment: @dandavis: I am seeing your comments from my mobile device and I will check when I reach home! Well, all I can say for now, keep trying! (that's what programmers do, sadly!)

Comment: I am getting sound (VERY quietly) if I have my face pretty much inside the Mic. If I can use this, can I amplify the sounds in JS?

Comment: you have to ride the system volume, turning it back up to hear the clip. the recording level itself seems fine. check your levels in the mixer. i've seen audio API editing routines in JS before, and was myself wondering if we could crop the extra ending silence and normalize the volume, but i havn't looked into it yet. i believe those tools were very green and "proof of concept"-y when i saw them last, maybe 6 months ago...

Comment: If I turn up my speakers to max, I can hear it at a normal volume. However for the purpose it seems quite a pain. The silence at the end, which I know is an issue is also not great. Hope this project actually gets fixed and completed!

Comment: @dandavis I'm using recorder.js for audio recording and saving it in mp3 format. It double the length of audio e.g if i record audio for 10 sec, it gives me 20 sec audio and the last 10 secs are blank. Working fine in wav format.